# ImportError while importing winreg module of python

Tags: python, winreg

I wanted to use winreg module of python for working with windows registry.
But when I try to import winreg module, it gives ImportError.

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Dec 11 2006, 11:39:03) 
[GCC 4.1.1 20061130 (Red Hat 4.1.1-43)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import __winreg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: No module named __winreg
>>> import _winreg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

Do I need to install this module separately ?
Any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: check these links - http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320761/importerror-no-module-named-winreg-python3

Comment: @avasal Your first link is broken. In python3 it is instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't work on Linux.

> _winreg - Windows registry access
>
> Availability: Windows.
>
> New in version 2.0. These functions expose the Windows registry API to
>   Python. Instead of using an integer as the registry handle, a handle
>   object is used to ensure that the handles are closed correctly, even
>   if the programmer neglects to explicitly close them.
>
> This module exposes a very low-level interface to the Windows
>   registry; it is expected that in the future a new winreg module will
>   be created offering a higher-level interface to the registry API.

source: http://docs.python.org/release/2.1.2/lib/module--winreg.html

Comment: Thanks Ashwini ! Now my question is can i also not use winreg on cygwin also ?

Comment: Yes, I was successfully able to use cygwinreg on cygwin. Thanks everybody for the help !

Comment: As the author, I'm glad to hear that my library helped you.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to import a [windows only](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) module on a *nix platform (RedHat is not Windows).

> **_winreg – Windows registry access**
>
> Platforms: Windows