# Is it possible to use win32gui/pywin32 on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pywin32, win32gui, winreg

I have a certain software written for Windows invironment and I'm trying to port it in Linux. It is heavily based on pywin32 (among other two python GUI libraries like Tkinter and wxPython) and depends on win32gui.

I don't have pywin32 installed on my Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS system, so I've downloaded the source and tried to build it, writing:

```
python setup.py
```

Consequently, I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 82, in <module>
    import _winreg
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

But from what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133506/importerror-while-importing-winreg-module-of-python/11133611#11133611) for `winreg`, this library is Windows only.

Does this mean that I can't use win32gui/pywin32 on Linux?

If so, could you suggest some way around it if possible or an alternative python gui for Linux? I already have in mind Tkinter and wxPython, but I'm not sure which is best for my case though.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @anms_pro I can't really recall, it's been a while...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using one of the two instead of trying to find a way to solve that. I used Tkinter in Python GUI but it's just my personal preference.