# ImportError: No module named _winreg python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, wmi

I tried to install wmi in my system which is running with python2.7.12.

installed WMI using pip :  pip install wmi

But it shows below error

```
>>> import wmi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
    from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
>>>
```

Then, I tried to install win32 python module. But its failed with "ImportError: No module named _winreg".

Full error message:

```
root@srv1:/home/srv1/Downloads/pywin32-220# python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 82, in <module>
    import _winreg
ImportError: No module named _winreg
root@srv1:/home/srv1/Downloads/pywin32-220#
```

Comment: you are installing pywin32 in linux system?

Comment: Look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133506/importerror-while-importing-winreg-module-of-python

Comment: @Enix can you guide me how to install python wmi module in ubuntu machine ? .

Comment: i think wmi package could only be installed in windows system. why you need to use wmi in ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not trying to install wmi in ubuntu. I just tried to monitor my windows machines using wmi to retrieve custom metrics. I preferred python language for this. can you share your suggestion on how to use wmi module in python to monitor the windows machines/servers?