# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_winreg'

Tags: python

```
D:\>pip install selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,

  File "d:\program files\python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, get_src_prefix
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 23, in <module>
    USER_CACHE_DIR = appdirs.user_cache_dir("pip")
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 43, in user_cache_dir
    path = os.path.normpath(_get_win_folder("CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA"))
  File "d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\appdirs.py", line 203, in _get_win_folder_from_registry

    import _winreg

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_winreg'
```

Comment: try doing `pip install --upgrade pip` first, then try doing that again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Navigate to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320761/importerror-no-module-named-winreg-python3) for your query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320761/importerror-no-module-named-winreg-python3 this may help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importError: no module named \_winreg python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320761/importerror-no-module-named-winreg-python3)

Answer (score 0):

Call `winregistry`
If not installed, do `pip install winregistry`

> `>>> from winregistry import WinRegistry as Reg`

Go to https://pypi.org/project/winregistry/ for more info on how to install and use

Comment: But WinRegistry lib doesn't have the same functions, I think it cannot be used in place of winreg...